# Why the image does not get rendered by directly using src attribute in react?

Tags: reactjs

In my react project when I used `src=""` to provide address for an `img` element it didn't get rendered while I use the same image address with `import` it worked well.

This is when I used `src` attribute
[image: This is when I used src attribute]

This is when I used `import`
[image]

Why is this happens?

My working directory:

```
/public
    index.html
/src
App.js
index.js
    /components
        Contact.js
    /images
        felix.png
```

Comment: try wrapping your src using `{ }`. like this `<img src={"image path"} />`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add image to public directory so you can directly access it through src like :

```
<img src="/your-image-name.png" />
```